# Keras input Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Keras and I want to fit my train data in an Excel file.
My data has shape(1000, 5, 5), 1000 batches of data which are saved in 1000 spreadsheets,
each sheet contain 5 columns and rows:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | - | - | label |
| - | - | - | - | label |
| - | - | - | - | label |
| - | - | - | - | label |
| - | - | - | - | label |

I want Column A, B, C to be training features and Column E to be label.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing

df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
data_list = list(df.values())

def input_parser(x):
    Y = x.pop('E')
    features = ['A','B','C']
    X = x[features]
    return X, Y

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_list)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tuple(tf.py_function(func=input_parser,
                                                     inp=[x],
                                                     Tout=[tf.float32,tf.int64])),
                      num_parallel_calls=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

and then I got an error:

```
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

Why do I get this error?
How can I fit this data to my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try omitting your `map` function altogether and simply passing your data directly to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

spread_sheet1 = {'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 9], 'B': [3, 4, 6, 1, 4], 'C': [3, 4, 3, 1, 4], 'D': [1, 2, 6, 1, 4], 'E': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=spread_sheet1)

spread_sheet2 = {'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 4], 'B': [3, 5, 2, 1, 4], 'C': [9, 4, 1, 1, 4], 'D': [1, 5, 6, 1, 7], 'E': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=spread_sheet2)

features = ['A','B','C']
Y = np.stack([df1['E'].to_numpy(), df2['E'].to_numpy()])
Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y, dtype=tf.int32)
X = np.stack([df1[features].to_numpy(), df2[features].to_numpy()])
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=tf.float32)


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
print('Shape of X --> ', X.shape)
for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y)
```

```
Shape of X -->  (2, 5, 3)
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 3. 3.]
 [2. 4. 4.]
 [1. 6. 3.]
 [2. 1. 1.]
 [9. 4. 4.]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor([0 1 1 0 1], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 3. 9.]
 [2. 5. 4.]
 [1. 2. 1.]
 [2. 1. 1.]
 [4. 4. 4.]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor([1 1 1 0 1], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
```

Reading from an excel file `file.xlsx` with multiple sheets can be done like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
file_names = list(df.keys())

columns = ['A','B','C']
features = []
labels = []
for n in file_names:
  temp_df = df[n]
  features.append(temp_df[columns].to_numpy())
  labels.append(temp_df['E'].to_numpy())
  
Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.stack(labels), dtype=tf.int32)
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.stack(features), dtype=tf.float32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))

print('Shape of X --> ', X.shape)
for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question, but I want to fit my data of tenor with shape (5, 3), and the whole column E as one batch of input each time. So I can have features like (1000, 5, 3) with column A,B,C and label (1000,5), total 1000 batches of data.

Comment: So each batch of yours should contain 5 samples and 3 values from the columns A,B and C, so for example (32, 5, 3) where  32 is the batch size ? For your labels (32,5)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to use 5 sample as one input to predict the 5 label each time.

Comment: Updated answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, the result is exactly what I want. So after I use pd.read & sheet_name = None, is it turned to a dictionary of dataframe? How do I iterate those 1000 spreadsheet?

Comment: Trying to figure out the “File_name”, you say it’s a list of those sheet names, so is it Data=pd.read_excel(‘File.xlsx’, sheet_name=None), then file_name = Data.keys( ) ? Does the (sheet_name=None) read all the sheet at once?

Comment: I see, but I put all sheets in one file, it’s one excel file which contain 1000 sheets.

Comment: Oh. What is the shape of your dataframe when you read it like this `df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheet_name=None)`? Just do `print(df.shape)`

Comment: It turn out “Dict” object didn’t have shape, but when I use .asarray .shape it’s (1000, 5, 5)

Comment: Update answer. Does this solve your problem?